# Google Analytics Funnel issue

Tags: google-analytics

i have an issue with Google Analytics funnels setup.
I have 1 form in website, which is on 2 website pages. Form separated on 3 pages.

Form flow on page #1:

- /somepage/1
- /somepage/2
- /somepage/3 (this is the Goal)

Form flow on page #2:

- /1
- /2
- /3 (this is the Goal)

  So, i setup 2 different funnels for them (URLs like above). But, after saving i got, that the report for funnel #2 has not only /3 like "Goal Completion Location" but /somepage/3 too.

What do you suggest me to do in this case? How to resolve this issue?

Regards, Alex.

Comment: Can you post screenshots for your two goal configurations?

Comment: nyuen, no, I am sorry but I can not. 
Both of goals are Custom. Screen/Page set like in lists above.

Comment: Are you using regex matching, or "equals", or "begins with"?

Comment: I am using regex matching. All regexs are valid